# How to upload flutter ios project to testflight with widgetkit widget

Tags: flutter, xcode, swiftui, testflight, widgetkit

I have a flutter in which I have created widgetKit widget inside Xcode, now when I am trying it to upload it to testFlight it has uploaded but I can not see it in my apple testFlight. are there any special steps which I have to take with my widgetKit.

Comment: If app has error when publish to ``testflight``, ``Apple`` will send you a email for error detail. Can you check your email register with Apple Developer account

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to it as it is my company mail. I can ask them but why is it not showing its been 3 hours still nothing.

Comment: You can check my answer, as I know app has been rejected will not appear in ``TestFlight``, The detail of why ``Apple`` Reject should be sent via email. You can check it, fix and upload again. (Event ``Xcode archiver`` display popup that app have been success upload to ``TestFlight``, it might need to go through ``apple ``checking

Comment: After searching I have found that this issue seems to be due to my old Xcode version precise (13) so I have updated it and now it works, btw I did not get any mail.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact your company account holder and check the mail apple sent you. App will not appear in testflight (if it was rejected by apple). Here a short demo of the mail should be:

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "DemoApp". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the "Runner.app" bundle should contain a NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the "Runner.app" bundle should contain a NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the "Runner.app" bundle should contain a NSMotionUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:

ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data, or the app has one or more entitlements that permit such access. The Info.plist file for the "Runner.app" bundle should contain a NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources.

Best regards,
```